# My C# auto typer types more than the supposed input unless the input is 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this converts the input to an integer
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value, 0));
```

> this repeats the action and is where I think the problem is because if the input is 2 or more the program repeats like 50 times

```
    IEnumerable<string> strings = Enumerable.Repeat("", count);
    foreach (String str in strings)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code that you have inside that loop? I am not able to reproduce the stated behavior.

Comment: I have tested your code, the specific fact is that the program will input the textbox value circularly according to the count.Therefore, I am not sure what is wrong with you. Please describe your problem clearly.